# How to show custom toast dialog in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to show a custom `toast` (my own widget layout). I know how to show a custom `alert dialogue`, but that's not what I want.

**Because, `Alert dialogue`:**

1. Has a black background
2. Prevents touches when it's shown
3. Has to dismiss manually

I don't want to use `flutter` toast library because I can't make a custom layout with that.

I want to show my own layout on top of all other widgets and make it disappear after some time. Also, it should not prevent any input when it's shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [this library](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_oktoast) to add and customize your own toasts.

```
Widget widget = Center(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: Container(
          width: 40.0,
          height: 40.0,
           color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    ToastFuture toastFuture = showToastWidget(
      widget,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      onDismiss: () {
        print("the toast dismiss"); // the method will be called on toast dismiss.
      },
    );
```

Comment: Yes. This library is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**custom toast**

[image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Toast {
  static void show(
    String msg,
    BuildContext context) {
    Color textColor = Colors.white;
    Color backgroundColor = Colors.blueAccent;
    dismiss();
    Toast._createView(msg, context, backgroundColor, textColor);
  }

  static OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  static bool isVisible = false;

  static void _createView(
    String msg,
    BuildContext context,
    Color background,
    Color textColor,
  ) async {
    var overlayState = Overlay.of(context);

    final themeData = Theme.of(context);

    _overlayEntry = new OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => _ToastAnimatedWidget(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: background,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 10, 16, 10),
              child: Text(
                msg,
                softWrap: true,
                style: themeData.textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                  fontFamily: 'intel',
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    isVisible = true;
    overlayState.insert(_overlayEntry);
  }

  static dismiss() async {
    if (!isVisible) {
      return;
    }
    isVisible = false;
    _overlayEntry?.remove();
  }
}
class _ToastAnimatedWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _ToastAnimatedWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  _ToastWidgetState createState() => _ToastWidgetState();
}

class _ToastWidgetState extends State<_ToastAnimatedWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  bool get _isVisible => true; //update this value later

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        bottom: 50,
        child: AnimatedOpacity(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          opacity: _isVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
          child: widget.child,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**for call**

```
Toast.show(ApiContent.something_wrong, context);
```

[image]